# How would one put a degree with a flexible time to finish on one's resume?

Tags: degree

I am considering getting a part-time masters at my local university which has a flexible time to finish, i.e. the number of courses one takes in any given semester can vary.

Part of the appeal is that I do not want my degree to get in the way on my regular work. However, that necessitates that completing it could take anywhere from 2-4 years depending on what I am tasked with and such.

The primary goal of the masters degree is learning, so the specific impact on my resume is not all that important, but I am just wondering what I should say about it. In undergrad, I put my degree as

> "Bachelors of Computer Engineering Candidate --- Expected 2016"

What could I reasonably do in this case given that the degree could be anywhere from 2022-2025?

Comment: Why do you need to put anything about when you might complete it? Why not just say that you're a current student?

Comment: I wouldn’t put an estimate graduation day until you have one

Comment: @joeqwerty is that not usually how an in-progress degree is indicated?

Comment: So you “claim” a master’s in the future, then land a job now based on completion but then fail or stop the master’s. Question do you give up the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply list it [as "In Progress"](https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/listing-education-on-a-resume--cms-29396) if you are still pursuing it and you do not have an expected graduation date.